# Swapping the positions of adjacent characters in a string using indexing and loops in Python

Tags: python, string, for-loop, if-statement

Using just indexing and loops, how do you swap the positions of adjacent characters in a string, while making an exception for spaces?

I/P: HELLO WORLD

O/P: EHLLO OWLRD

This is the code I wrote:

```
s1=''
for j in range(0,len(s)-1,2):
   if(skip==1):
                    print()
                    skip=0
   elif(s[j].isspace()==False and s[j+1].isspace()==False):
                    s1=s1+s[j+1]+s[j]
   elif(s[j].isspace()==False and s[j+1].isspace()==True):
                    s1=s1+s[j]+" "
   elif(s[j].isspace()==True and s[j+1].isspace()==False and s[j+2].isspace()==False):
                    s1=s1+" "+s[j+2]+s[j+1]
                    skip=1
   elif(s[j].isspace()==True and s[j+1].isspace()==False and s[j+2].isspace()==True):
                    s1=s1+" "+s[j+1]
print("new string is",s1)
```

What exactly am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
inp = "HELLO WORLD"
expected = "EHLLO OWLRD"

for i in range(0, len(inp), 2):  # iterate in steps of two
    # check to make sure that we are not at end of string and charaters are not spaces
    if i+1 < len(inp) and inp[i] != " " and inp[i+1] != " ":
        # now do the string replacing
        temp1 = inp[i]
        temp2 = inp[i + 1]
        
        inp = inp[:i] + temp2 + temp1 + inp[i+2:]

# output to indicate the new string is what we expect        
print(inp)
print(expected)
print(inp == expected)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```py
s = "HELLO WORLD"

out = []
for w in map(list, s.split(" ")):
    for i in range(1, len(w), 2):
        w[i], w[i - 1] = w[i - 1], w[i]
    out.append("".join(w))

print(" ".join(out))
```

Prints:

```
EHLLO OWLRD
```